# Implementing a heap

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to implement a heap data structure, i wrote the maxHeapify method which builda maximum heap, and used it in my insert method in which i insert at the end then rearrange the heap to remain a max heap.
but it doesn't appear to work, any help would be appreciated.

```
    public class Heap { // a class to implement a heap
        private int[] data; // the heap array
        private static final int FRONT = 1;
        private int maxSize = 0;
        private int currentSize; // the current size of the data in the array

    public Heap(int maxSize) {
        this.currentSize = 1;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        data = new int[maxSize + 1];
    }

    public int[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getMaxSize() {
        return maxSize;
    }

    public void setMaxSize(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public int getCurrentSize() {
        return currentSize;
    }

    public void setCurrentSize(int currentSize) {
        this.currentSize = currentSize;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private int parent(int index) {// the index of the parent
        return index / 2;
    }

    private int left(int index) { // the index of the left child
        return (2 * index);
    }

    private int right(int index) { // the index of the right child
        return (2 * index) + 1;
    }

    private void swap(int i, int j) { // to swap two elements
        int temp = data[i];
        data[i] = data[j];
        data[j] = temp;
    }

    private void maxHeapify(int i) { // to build a max heap
        int left = left(i); // a method to return the index of the left child
        int right = right(i);// a method to return the index of the right child
        int largest = i;
        int x = currentSize;
        if (left <= currentSize && data[left] > data[i]) {
            largest = left;
        }
        if (right <= currentSize && data[right] > data[largest]) {
            largest = right;
        }
        if (largest != i) {
            int temp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[largest];
            data[largest] = temp;
            maxHeapify(largest);
        }
    }

    public void maxHeap() {
        for (int i = currentSize / 2; i >= 1; i--) {
            maxHeapify(i);
        }
    }

    public void insert(int newData) { // insert to the heap
        data[currentSize] = newData;
        currentSize++;
        maxHeapify(FRONT);


    }

    public int deleteMax() { // delete max from the heap
        int maxValue = data[FRONT];
        data[FRONT] = data[data.length - 1];
        maxHeapify(FRONT);
        currentSize--;
        return maxValue;

    }

    public void sort() {// heap sort
        maxHeap();
        for (int i = maxSize; i > 1; i--) {
            swap(FRONT, maxSize);
            maxSize--;
            maxHeapify(FRONT);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        maxSize = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {

        return maxSize == 0;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return currentSize == data.length;
    }

    public void printHeap() {// prints the heap
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxSize / 2; i++) {
            System.out.print(
                    " PARENT : " + data[i] + " LEFT CHILD : " + data[2 * i] + " RIGHT CHILD :" + data[2 * i + 1]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? What is the result and what should it be?

Comment: @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier try inserting 5,3,17,10,84,19,6,22,9 The result i get
 PARENT : 17 LEFT CHILD : 3 RIGHT CHILD :5
 PARENT : 3 LEFT CHILD : 10 RIGHT CHILD :84
 PARENT : 5 LEFT CHILD : 19 RIGHT CHILD :6
 PARENT : 10 LEFT CHILD : 22 RIGHT CHILD :9

What it should be
 PARENT : 84 LEFT CHILD : 22 RIGHT CHILD :19
 PARENT : 22 LEFT CHILD : 17 RIGHT CHILD :10
 PARENT : 19 LEFT CHILD : 5 RIGHT CHILD :6
 PARENT : 17 LEFT CHILD : 3 RIGHT CHILD :9

Comment: I'm not sure why you implement your custom data structure you could use built in data structure http://www.journaldev.com/1642/java-priority-queue-priorityqueue-example

Comment: @SauliusNext  i am taking a data structure course at the university and i was asked to implement the heap data structure .

Comment: If possible try to edit your question and improve it directly, not by writing the debug infos in the comments. It is hard to read such as it is.

Comment: @gue i haven't changed any thing in the code, the full code is provided in the question.

Comment: I am aware. What I meant with "debug infos" is your answer to the comment of @M.Schwarzer-Haverbier what you have already tried and what does not work. This seems to me should be part of your question.

Comment: @ gue i am sorry i miss understood your question and yes it is what i have tried and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your function maxHeapify works when you add new number on root of your heap. I mean to say in maxHeapify, you are moving from root to child. But during insertion you are inserting element to the last. You have to move from down to up.

maxHeapify : going root to down.

After inserting element to data array, you have to check upward from child to parent exact opposite of maxHeapify.

Comment: i swap the elements in the following way int temp = data[i];
   data[i] = data[largest];
   data[largest] = temp;   and it does not work

Comment: the heap array which i insert to

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    /**
     * Parent.
     *
     * @param pos the pos
     * @return the int
     */
    private int parent(int pos)
    {
        return pos / 2;
    }

    /**
     * Left.
     *
     * @param pos the pos
     * @return the int
     */
    private int left(int pos)
    {
        return (2 * pos);
    }

    /**
     * Right.
     *
     * @param pos the pos
     * @return the int
     */
    private int right(int pos)
    {
        return (2 * pos) + 1;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if is leaf.
     *
     * @param pos the pos
     * @return true, if is leaf
     */
    private boolean isLeaf(int pos)
    {
        if (pos >=  (size / 2)  &&  pos <= size)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Swap.
     *
     * @param fpos the fpos
     * @param spos the spos
     */
    private void swap(int fpos,int spos)
    {
        int tmp;
        tmp = data[fpos];
        data[fpos] = data[spos];
        data[spos] = tmp;
    }

    /**
     * Max heapify.
     *
     * @param pos the pos
     */
    private void maxHeapify(int pos)
    {
        if (!isLeaf(pos))
        { 
            if ( data[pos] < data[left(pos)]  || data[pos] < data[right(pos)])
            {
                if (data[left(pos)] > data[right(pos)])
                {
                    swap(pos, left(pos));
                    maxHeapify(left(pos));
                }else
                {
                    swap(pos, right(pos));
                    maxHeapify(right(pos));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insert.
     *
     * @param newElement the element
     */
    public void insert(int newElement)
    {
        data[++size] = newElement;
        int current = size;

        while(data[current] > data[parent(current)])
        {
            swap(current,parent(current));
            current = parent(current);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You required to shift up after adding the new element at last position.
For an example.

```
public void insert(int value) {
            if (heapSize == data.length)
                  throw new HeapException( storage is overflow");
            else {
                  heapSize++;
                  data[heapSize - 1] = value;
                  siftUp(heapSize - 1);
            }
      } 
 private void siftUp(int nodeIndex) {
 //code to hepify.
}
```